# Ubuntu 22.04 and Win 10 dual boot restart loop

Tags: dual-boot, 22.04, windows-10

I have tried to make Ubuntu 22.04 and Windows 10 dual boot configuration. I made the stick with MBR and NTFS format, followed the Ubuntu installer, chose Install along side Windows 10 option and when it was done it asked me to restart the laptop. I did so and laptop was stuck with Lenovo logo on the screen, so i pressed Ctrl+Alt+Delete and now the laptop is stuck restarting every time it gets to that Lenovo logo screen. I can enter Bios and loaded setup defaults and the problem still persists. This is what boot tab in the Bios looks like: https://pasteboard.co/Wbb6My7dRXf3.jpg

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: make sure the battery is charged

Comment: I would turn off network boot, the PXE & IPv4 options. You are not using those & it just slows boot process for system to look for network. Did you install in UEFI boot mode? Be sure to boot live installer in UEFI mode. Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the BootInfo summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed. Use often updated ppa version over somewhat older ISO with your USB installer  or any working install.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair &